# Implementing e-mail verification in Okta

Tags: api, authentication, okta

We're using Okta as an IDM provider and are trying to determine how to fulfill a specific use case that we currently use for one of our applications. Here is the current application flow:

1. User enters website
2. User enters e-mail and password to create an account
3. An e-mail gets sent to the address entered in step 2 with a verification link
4. User clicks on the link and the IDM system marks them as verified
5. User can now log into the system using the credentials entered in step 2

As we look at the Okta user creation flows, we only see e-mails being sent for the following two flows/API calls: 1. Create a user without credentials or recovery questions; 2. Create Users with Recovery Questions.

All other flows (at least the ones that we're aware of) create a user with credentials and activate the user right away and allow login without an e-mail being sent.

Can the scenario above be created in Okta with a combination of API calls? Basically, can we create a user and keep it as "staged" until they click on a verification e-mail? Or is this a highly custom scenario? Also, we are not using multi-factor authentication so we don't have that as an option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two API calls to achieve this. First is to create user with credentials and activate parameter in the url set to false. This will create users with credentials but status for the user will be STAGED. Use the user Id to make second call that is activate user and set the sendEmail query parameter in the url to true. This will activate user and send activation email to user's primary email address.

See the two calls below.

```
POST /api/v1/users?activate=false

{
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "{{firstName}}",
    "lastName": "{{lastName}}",
    "email": "{{email}}",
    "login": "{{login}}"
  },
  "credentials": {
    "password" : { "value": "{{password}}$" }
  }
}
```

User will be created with status = STAGED. Get the user id from this call. Make the second call using this user id.

```
POST /api/v1/users/{{userId_from_last_call}}/lifecycle/activate?    sendEmail=true
```

Please note that second call will set the user's status to be ACTIVE and also send activation email to user's email address. Clicking on the link user will be prompted to select security image (and recovery question if not already set).

If user logs in with the email address instead of clicking on activation email, user will be prompted to set security image/question the same way.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your input. I did experiment with this and the only dangling concern is the time of activation. Ideally, the account would activate when the user clicks the link in the e-mail, but that may or may not end up being a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the 2nd call /api/v1/users/{{userId_from_last_call}}/lifecycle/activate doesnt verify the user before activating them.

What I need is

```
1) User creates an account with their email and password

2) Account is staged

3) Verification email is sent with activate link

4) User account only get activated by clicking the link
```

Cant seem to find a way to do this simple solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the sendEmail parameter may not have been included in the call to lifecycle/activate.

The lifecycle/active endpoint name can be confusing, it *starts* activation it doesn't actually activate a user. With sendEmail if forces the email verification where the user receives a link with an embedded one-time-token. The token will be returned to Okta, usually be clicking the link, or it could be returned through the API. Once the token is received, the user is activated.

With the one-time token to verify the email address the flow should work exactly as requested above. Reference: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#activate-user.